# SQL attribute FROM and WHERE in R data.frames

Tags: r, dataframe

Please how to select data using SQL like features in R data.frames ?

Let's say I have the following data.frame :

```
Names Numbers
A       1
B       2 
C       3
```

How to select number 2 using strings "B" and "Numbers" and not data[2,2] ? I would like to use something like data["B", "Numbers"] but it doesn't work, help please !!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `[`, or `subset` when using `data.frames`. Note that `[` has a `drop = TRUE` argument which will coerce to an atomic vector if a single value / column is returned.

```
DF <- data.frame(Names = LETTERS[1:3], Numbers = 1:3)

subset(DF, Names == 'B', select = Numbers)
##   Numbers
## 2       2
DF[DF$Names == 'B', 'Numbers']
## [1] 2
DF[DF$Names == 'B', 'Numbers', drop = FALSE]
##   Numbers
## 2       2
```

I like [`data.tables`. FAQ 2.16](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf) describes the similarities between SQL and `data.table` syntax

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(DF)

DT[Names == 'B', Numbers]
## [1] 2
# using keys
setkey(DT,Names)
DT['B'][,list(Numbers)]
##     Numbers
## 1:        2
```

or there is `sqldf` which lets you use `SQL` in data.frames

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf('select Numbers from DF where Names == "B"')
##   Numbers
## 1       2
```